# APEX dynamic action not copying value

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to get the drop down value copied into the text box with out submitting the form.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So when I run the page "cow" is populated in the copied value but the value does not change when I change the drop down.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I tried java script and that did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Set Type of the Action to JavaScript Expression. Then enter the following in the JavaScript Expression field:

```
$v('P5_MY_SELECT')
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
apex.item('P5_MY_SELECT').getValue()
```